# let $B=(f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}/f(x)=x^ke^{cx};\mbox{ }k\in \mathbb{Z},\mbox{ }c\in \mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{Z}^*=\mathbb{Z}^+\bigcup \left \{ 0\right \}$ and let $B=(f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}/f(x)=x^ke^{cx};\mbox{ }k\in \mathbb{Z^*},\mbox{ }c\in \mathbb{C})$

Prove that $B$ is a linearly independent set

Comment: What are $y_1,y_2$?

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff   Sorry I have a mistake

Comment: Any thoughts on how to prove it?

Comment: @user63192:  you mean $k \in Z^*$, right?

Comment: @Robert Lewis    Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $B$ is a linearly independent set, it is necessary to show that for every *finite* set $\mathscr F = \{f_1, f_2, . . ., f_N \} \subset B$ any  relation of the form $\sum_1^N c_i f_i = 0$ with $c_i \in \Bbb C$ implies $c_i = 0$ for all $i$, $1 \le i \le N$.  Such a relation, written out in full, would read $\sum_i^N c_i e^{cx} x ^{k_i}  =0$ for some set $\{ k_i, 1 \le i \le N \}$ of $N$ distinct integers $k_i \in Z^*$.  Dividing through by $e^{cx} \ne \ 0$ leave us with the polynomial $\sum_1^N c_i x^{k_i} = 0$.  But a polynomial can only vanish identically if all of its coefficients do.  Thus the $c_i$ are all zero and the set $B$ is linearly independent.  QED.

I can't deal with infinite sums, since that involves a notion of convergence, and no topology was specified for $B$.  But I think the algebraic result (for finite sums) is what was called for here.

I assumed the OP meant  $k \in Z^*$; hope that was right.

Cheers, and of course,

*Fiat Lux*!

Comment: Thanks Robert have a nice day :)

Comment: You're more than welcome; my pleasure, sir! And a very pleasant weekend to you as well!